# read index.html file first in joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-template

I have a template in joomla without index.php I only have index.html, css file, javascript file and tempalteDetails

How to change joomla configuration to see index.html file fist to index.php?

I do a test and create index.php file, and yes joomla read fist this file because now it show me a white page.

I change my htaccess.html file... fist I write this

DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
and second the extension.. first htaccess.html and now is .htaccess

But  I have the same problem I don´t see index.html.

Any idea!!!

Comment: If this is a valid joomla template, it should help to just rename the file to index.php. However it still leaves the question open, why it was named index.html in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im not sure what template you have downloaded but I can tell you for sure the developers must have no idea what they are doing. `.html` files are used for security only in Joomla and they are NOT to be used for template structures. Instead of answering your question, I will say, find a new template.